# Lavavel Middleware does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I have recently moved to Laravel from the normal php and I have managed to finish a project in my localhost, everything works fine at least to my expectation but when I moved my files to the server, I am experincing a middleware issue.

Now I have a middleware called isAdmin which was created using the artisan command. I have also registerd the class in the kernel as:

```
'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
```

My isAdmin middleware cass is configued as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class isAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

this middleware works fine on my localhost, I already grouped all routes using the middleware like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function () {
        //routes that uses this middlewares here
});
```

When I uploaded my code to a shared hosting server, I get error:

```
Target class [App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin] does not exist.
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?? I also realize that I can not run artisan command because the current php version on the server is less that 8.0.2

Comment: PHP 8.2 has not yet been released. Whatever problem it is that you're having with `artisan`, it's not because of PHP 8.2

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I mean to say 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
use App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin;

Route::group(['middleware' => IsAdmin::class], function () {
    //routes that uses this middlewares here
});
```

Comment: aparently I created a middleware isAdmin and I'm calling it as IsAdmin. Your solution made me look at the spelling again. Thank you.

Any Idea why it's working on localhost even with this error?

Comment: i faced the same error as you in the shared hosting but , idk why .